# I can't set manage rights to outside-domain accounts in Google Calendar (GApps)

Tags: google-calendar, sharing

I would like to add some users to be able to manage my GApps calendar. When the user is in my domain, there's no problem but when he's outside I can just set options like `See all event details` and `See only free/busy (hide details)`. I need to set `Make changes to events` but it won't let me.

Why?

PS: in domain management in Calendar settings I have set sharing options like:

> **Outside Mydomain.net - set user ability**
>
> By default, calendars are not
> shared outside mydomain.net. Select the highest level of sharing that
> you want to allow for your users.
>
> - ***Share all information, and outsiders can change calendars***

Answer (score 4):

It works now. I don't know where the error is but I think that it's important to set **Share all information, and outsiders can change calendars** in Domain management Calendar settings and then you must wait until the change applies to google servers.

Comment: In my experience, it can take up to an hour for some changes like this to take effect. In some cases, the Google Apps control panel alerts you to this, in other cases, it's not prominently mentioned.